# Spring Expression Language (SpEL): check empty string?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, guava, spring-el

What is a canonical way to check if the String is null or empty using SpEL?
I would like to achieve the same result as `Strings.isNullOrEmpty(myString)` from Guava does.

My candidates:

1. `"#myString.?length=0"`
2. `"#myString = ''"`

Not sure if any is canonical, and the documentation is pretty vague (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operators)

Answer (score 11):

This is how it's done according to latest documentation:

not null or empty `#myString > ''`

null or empty `#myString <= ''`

not null or blank `#myString?.trim() > ''`

null or blank `#myString?.trim() <= ''`

Comment: Which paragraph explains this? I couldn't find it in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions

Comment: Here's the link to how relational operators work: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-operators-relational and the rest are just trivial assumptions based on the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any Java method on an object, e.g. `#myString.length()`, `#myString.isEmpty()` or `#myString.isBlank()`. I'd say, that would be the canonical way to check whether a string is empty or blank.

For null or empty: `#myString == null || #myString.isEmpty()`

For null or blank: `#myString == null || #myString.isBlank()`

You can test this with:

```
System.out.println(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#root?.isEmpty()").getValue("x")); // false
System.out.println(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#root?.isEmpty()").getValue("")); // true
System.out.println(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#root?.isEmpty()").getValue((Object) null)); // null
System.out.println(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#root == null || #root.isEmpty()").getValue("x")); // false
System.out.println(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#root == null || #root.isEmpty()").getValue("")); // true
System.out.println(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#root == null || #root.isEmpty()").getValue((Object) null)); // true
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   /*
    list=['a','b']
    list=[]
    list=""
   */
   ${empty list}//false
   ${empty list1}//true
   ${empty list2}//true
```

Comment: I don't think this is Java or SpEL.

Comment: I would suggest you either modify and correct this answer or remove it altogether as it's not what the OP has asked about.

Comment: I wrote code for JSTL way and now i changed its with SpEL